# Logarithmic funtions

Tags: calculus

Calculate the derivative of $y=\cos x \ln\cos^2 x$.

How do I do this? I see that this uses both the product rule and the chain rule, but how do I evaluate the derivative of $\ln\cos^2 x$?

Comment: Could you re-type the function in question?  Could be read in a couple of different ways.

Comment: hm.. I'm sorry about that, I don't know how to retype it, but it's y=cos(x)ln((cos^2)x)

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use $\LaTeX$.  See the [guide of how to typeset math equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @bob.sacamento: I converted the formatting to LaTeX. The notation is not ambiguous. It is conventional not to crowd trig expressions with parentheses unless needed. For example, you wouldn't think twice about $\sin x \cos x$. No need for parentheses unless I *really did intend* $\sin(x\cos x)$, right?

Comment: latex? lol now I know. But awesome job, that's the exact way I wanted it to be read!

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\ln \cos^2 x$ is
$$(\ln \cos^2 x)'=(2\ln\cos x)'=2(\ln\cos x)'=2\frac{(\cos x)'}{\cos x}=-2\tan x$$